# How to add an input quantity field that correlates with MSLB field?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I am on SP Server 2010/InfoPath 2010. I have a MSLB field in a form that pulls from a simple SP list so that a user can select multiple items, that is done. But how can I add a add a corresponding field for quantity per item?

For example, the list contains:

Item A
Item B
Item C
Item D
Item E

User selects Items A and D, but wants a quantity of 5 for Item A, and a quantity of 3 for Item D. Is this possible? Should I be using different features?

Thank you,
Joni

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like instead of an MSLB, what you should have is a repeating table that has:

- A dropdown listing all the items in the list
- A quantity field

That way, the user can add a row for each item they want to select, end enter the quantity.